# When can you NOT replace milk with almond milk?

Tags: substitutions, milk, dairy, almond-milk

I saw a video on making pizza and it seemed easy enough, but the recipe required milk to make the dough.

I try to avoid dairy and realized that once when making scrambled eggs that required milk in the recipe and switching it for almond milk there was a puddle of water under the scrambled eggs and I assumed it was because there's not as much fat and more water content in almond milk than milk.

[YouTube link to pizza recipe with milk](https://youtu.be/9TjUWnAK0cg)

Comment: Pizza dough does not contain milk or other milk product.

Comment: & it's quite possible to make scrambled eggs with water instead of milk*, if you have to. If they puddle liquid, you over-cooked them. Serve before they fully set, not after. They'll continue to cook on the plate. *I always consider omlette, water, scrambled, milk - but I've often forgotten & can't really tell the difference ;)

Comment: Linking to a 10 minute youtube video isn't a good way to provide us with the recipe, which we could read inside 10 seconds.

Comment: In my experience, it's better to think of almond milk as "almond stock" for cooking purposes. There is a longstanding legal dispute between dairy and almond milk producers on account of these kinds of confusions.

Comment: Having tried many substitutions for dairy milk with other "milks" (almond, soy, oat, and more), there's a really wide array of results: everything from "can't tell the difference" to "adequate" to "absolutely disastrous." Unfortunately, this question is sort of broad as it currently stands.

Comment: @Erica_ that's a great detailed answer considering you provide an example gor each case, then people would know when it is a good substitution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In baking, you can almost always replace cow's milk with a non-dairy product.  It's usually a matter of taste.  In stove-top cooking, you may have to experiment more, especially if making creamy sauces.  In that case, thicker, non-dairy milks should be tried.  Here, again taste will probably be important, but it is probably important to pay attention to viscosity as well.  Even foods based on dairy, like yogurt and ice cream, can be made with substitutes.  Consider that many non-dairy milks are sweetened, so you will want to factor that in as well.

If you are avoiding dairy, you can always find a work-around.  In some cases it will not be noticed, in others, the result might be a little different, but that doesn't mean it can't be delicious.

Having said this, scrambled eggs can easily be made with no addition of dairy, and most pizza doughs that I am familiar with do not use dairy either.  So, those preparations are easy enough to deal with in this regard.